# Tag merge: internet-radio into streaming

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we merge [internet-radio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-radio) into [streaming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/streaming)? I don't think we really need a separate tag just for internet radio when it is already covered under streaming.

Answer (score 4):

No. They're not synonyms. They don't mean the same thing.

I agree they're definitely related ([internet-radio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-radio) is likely a subset of [streaming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/streaming)) but I don't think they're close enough to warrant just doing away with. If we infer video streaming to be part of [streaming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/streaming), we're also dealing with drastically different technologies and applications.

I'm not saying that things might not need tidying up .[streaming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/streaming) as it is might need splitting up into things that actually mean something rather than a word that means different things in different contexts...